# Getting pdf file from server, trying to display it in HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf

PDF

> 

```
%PDF-1.4
1 0 obj
<<
/Title (��)
/Creator (��wkhtmltopdf 0.12.4)
/Producer (��Qt 4.8.7)
/CreationDate (D:20221215173305Z)
>>
endobj
3 0 obj
<<
/Type /ExtGState
/SA true
/SM 0.02
/ca 1.0
/CA 1.0
/AIS false
/SMask /None>>
endobj
4 0 obj
[/Pattern /DeviceRGB]
endobj
8 0 obj
[0 /XYZ 306  
743.750000  0]
endobj
9 0 obj
<<
/__WKANCHOR_2 8 0 R
>>
endobj
11 0 obj
<</Title (��1BE 9B/ 'D%J,'1 1894812406)
  /Parent 10 0 R
  /Dest /__WKANCHOR_2
  /Count 0
>>
endobj
10 0 obj
<</Type /Outlines /First 11 0 R
/Last 11 0 R>>
endobj
12 0 obj
<<
/Type /Catalog
/Pages 2 0 R
/Outlines 10 0 R
/PageMode /UseOutlines
/Dests 9 0 R
>>
endobj
5 0 obj
<<
/Type /Page
/Parent 2 0 R
/Contents 13 0 R
/Resources 15 0 R
/Annots 16 0 R
/MediaBox [0 0 595 842]
>>
endobj
15 0 obj
<<
/ColorSpace <<
/PCSp 4 0 R
/CSp /DeviceRGB
/CSpg /DeviceGray
>>
/ExtGState <<
/GSa 3 0 R
>>
/Pattern <<
>>
/Font <<
/F6 6 0 R
/F7 7 0 R
>>
/XObject <<
>>
>>
endobj
16 0 obj
[ ]
endobj
13 0 obj
<<
/Length 14 0 R
/Filter /FlateDecode
>>
stream
x��]Ko�����y���&,`��90l`���l��A�=��f�%�k�e�j���?V���ԧ������ͧ��������Fl�ݿ&��a���C�Am�??ݼ7�K�?�~��V�6���m���t�����_�kd�������_��M��nl0۶}?~�AH���h���.�m��ͷ���B�Rۮ/������:�rk����o��c����z����V���k�k�
����)]���7,��`䎂�E�ay?p����ӳm@6o�Ư����z����7w2���K�8������͝J�v�Q\�(B�E�i)Oo� sn�}�s��àM��ܗ�{�K�( 
�\��QB��Jw�4vy1����P��c���J9��,�iĠ��)^�h)�8a��=�ι���]�  �5�P�rv^�6�؁�m�&�B�g�~��ءk�,��
Pa O�������
�Vy/��!�-
�
�J�D7��'\tr��
�MM���j܁L�Jܳ��G�a������3;:�f�g���Б�y�#����P:���nms����3�Ec�Z�jBg�L��Rg��[=}���,U/KU-�����-��'Y�^te��X}�,��&�L}��At1
�sٵ�]�"�[��?    �*w�
���爏z�6K�[��Yy��]Ъ��#i�ir��aD��%_1��    �j`�&u�]����y �dq:1��a����z�h��I��gf��{">׷Iq}n��_pQ����ː��W��d���CI*���4'��8�Y�:>
�{������[�R@��[o��F?��wA2"Zv��#p    �[G�\Ÿ�ԔWi}���v�[/m����JPE.=�B{�0/1�    1++$+]�n�B<�q����!9t��9GCu�����6ƃ1��t ��ǐ���
?�Ȧ�u����
���VŬ޵4�j�st��B[�jh�0%~���ʁ2
�K6
�Ykg�M*�U��b�
 W�3��]u�=
�!���FL<�F�ꌂW:>�A�a��>�!��S!M�tu���̰�{ĵ�    ��hd�\�[��h�\^;�!�y�D�7xX��肇�RY�5E�zD��W�:��V��ٻ��Ӕt!��MIrL���S�z�`�C�Ɉ��#��!G
�:S�z�J�����>��l���X�ѽ3�<�K�a0b^0FK�j¦.T��T,���oF�j,�b�!=;b�W�V�+T��Ar��\��>a������TNATt���/Z�J�ʆBuŁ�Bŝaּ��U�fY�#�׼Z�?����1k�6�Qo���h�.��z_�Ԏ��
����!���FL<�����4�K��u���I��)�\�^Ҧ�������}�=��cP�.鮂8->T��IΞަ%�����0���`BJ���Ęi�4pϣ6���^@j����Y��)(�[��J��џ4�@���ew&��0i,�~���E'kቅ0%���H+�@�d���RH��!<�^wC�!G�D���U��i��-8�����3z����~�ty���U��b�*��Mz���x�);�3��U,�?�
´ɪG�ew6:{_+�e̥���T:5M���;���kF�̇���Y���3�u6���}z�"�x��B*    a�fM���b���2�h1�$6r��&�n%�im���M����U�.95S����6S�Z��lmd���,��m��wPKdvX��GeHFD͎��Q5��"o���QǗ�i��Ђ�~8�L�j��W~�2yҵZ�"��T�����W��R ަ�
g�2N����mz\R˛�mz�t�;q��>���!Y���#kz�N���;�(Ҩ    E�&G��ZO`�)tzB$g�߾��&�o�_h���N�ߒ��&%n�_h�H��R�l{R"C2"*vD����W�/����YyN��{�hX�>��0�'Zx�JAP�J����q�u��_�R˶h6�!H�'o|C��[�Bbf�!YM\�5$^��kK�N1q�����B�ݐ����+
�E�{qz 5uY��3,�����A
�0G�h����$Ð�-Q�Y�><Ѯŝfy�EDT�Ez���y��*� jJn���(Fsۆ>�}?d�dDt숚y?d
�:s�S�����ԨPr蚏9�5��/�qĘmT{�<���T��ש�ê�[|m@�G����ƶ����%������8�N��Wo��pf��!YMj�7�]�I��z��j.����Q���t��������"['4ml���eIAc�B�޳A=$�n��#oT�Nc��YsQ��\����DS��f�~C�&\]ɶ�/s9�T�#i]zZ���Ѧ8H��o�Ղ��Wfy�ֵk��P�Sћ�[��k�ւx��"1�q�m����Z���T`�d5�5���Lj�sb�Ũ�E�Vό��^�]ؙw��#�sF�L���|�Ii�������7��C,j�v�F!�
�l^�Voޱ�ڟ�Zn)xj"�$�N������X�K�L���ކ�_G��)���    �G��?�������[k����(h�z��?g�o�ލ�?Dt�a��:�ٶ������K����WM�5��B}�m�G��t,r!d}�\4�V���D���*Aˉ����'gm����N r�R�A5*� MBV����]��q<Ż��"�n��AW�ם�.��u%@xD�[��']�b5[A��lE��n�Q)� ��T�a��֋�VU���������Oʋ�*U�X�n��=n�T��E��1%]���(��$ױ�%�q_B�N�}�T4�*�A�A�jD�vrg"
����8e�`�⠇~����e�2��n
endstream
endobj
14 0 obj
2920
endobj
17 0 obj
<< /Type /FontDescriptor
/FontName /QRAAAA+Cairo-Regular
/Flags 4 
/FontBBox [-224 -430 1667 1084 ]
/ItalicAngle 0 
/Ascent 1303 
/Descent -571 
/CapHeight 1303 
/StemV 50 
/FontFile2 18 0 R
>>
endobj
18 0 obj
<<
/Length1 19192 
/Length 21 0 R
/Filter /FlateDecode
>>
stream
x��|\�ו��CBBH��K ���I=x�� 0ƀyc�Cm�v�Cm'�`2���X�d�Y��v�4�d2�f2�N6��v����:�Lg�ͯi'�_&ux|��>    �vl��Χ�Ч�{�=�����sA!��#��c�7nu�)y�=�G��~�����   B��Юށ���ʅP|G�!8 �
�   ��D��84zp��O��!�����ȿM���%����ީh]@��u����wtW��V��!"Q�~Ѱ�h�+j������G ��p�k;l�5�r�}��e:r�BtaO@���Y�9��������5�-!�F��K5�t|��I����E7=�x��@��MxJ;�:J�{�~ì�K���K���^z��{�r"#��4Ij���Z�ds.wR��&%]�$�&�W鶴/,�ڌF����������\W�9W)�KF�g6�/�(� I�@J��;���x�;#
��Y�6G�#�\C}]Q�^���ؼ���������Ѵ@ K�R�@0G���zٴ|V �`p�6ԉ�� 4���x�Z��DBg"lL��Ŝ�=��+��R���ڋ�C���[�?f�8�
��4��G���w�֥g`� %�abl���q�(����*,zh��v8�̹}}��v:]qj�<#�������b���ؒ�g�y⒧뙙�^��J/+�i�AP4_ bf<���˗q����N�t�ݻRJK���#O7t�W��ݭ�rgei���X����?�Ҝ��碢���A�11rE�*>�`��z|d�Å�)��f�#���-ϱ����K� x�fξ�*�^}��?��Aַ�/�^�Yb9��ܽ2e�ć�:�O�|�Y��q�F*�qq9Y�MB�E*�J�T�"ad�0��__,啦����,Cl4�;��R��DG��FF�wWo2g�Qw�@1>�5I5A�)����j3�u�<sv��2
P(�[Ћ&�N�M�=�"���pb��VVw"@u��ކ��@��f�H�"�_�<�[+��Ʀ�葪*����f��TaQlE�S8�����}*Ʃ�����p�}d�i�-QHM�6��CB���H�<!��pQ��3��khx�|}clܜ�2>��oM�[,K�߾�`�7��̧NAM��'7�l`�i��7p�c�(��L�J�44̶��zD���B���H�X$���;t��D�m��0̹����Y��X&�˩�i�ֺ���tE�G�u��3���P�%U�L����3B�C4�b����#�D���
V�5���  7c��[+W������;�Xɯϵ�@�բ  s����6%J��� ��uٛZq����� 41�1[5���;0<_�h2�Fh%��"j��v9����E�k:��W��eJ~qk)ӿ��l6nv�K���=0����粐�q�z���I��x�dI1�A���D����+[%�M+i3�g�ĶI�9�9Z�dx�#�u~���f����S��[��<�   �&�@E�45U>5�/ߎu�⢮��榺�Խmrbrdt|�`�>��tg�؁Ø`ϙ��56��h������ng?qvvC}Wg�B�MLT��9i*n�!�����F7�al4tl?��v��T ���l������  G�cu����j�����T�2g2���h=lH��J$Ҹ�������姆H�ih(��������b>lQ0�=D��Ys����w�F
1n����%�����oS
�=C4�O�8��Ys�}5��5�kH3�tl��-��=3?ܳ��t��?�/--+1R��U��;���<�f��������&�X�Ɨ�=M-�$h�:*���]S�5��jh���O�>hU��;�V�"x����~����I�~��;���ƒ��b� ����Lnɳ��\�o�7Q[�����6w�����(��.*),�vegǪ�Bi�����鲲�;<�@r�P�D��Tj���ˤ�8U�up��0N��CBx<
����U�T!U�,y��+��bd^��x��!�Z�R�����8��z�����\��s�.�b�
��.�kt�0.9%)9R�ij�'"Oa�SLԈ�E`�$N��d�al�*I9<��N8���/�����J�CO�S1 �j��9I$8w����I�ӕ��A�h=6I������j����:c�9��"����F���"�5��#Z���MV�w�}�V��ZU�-�*+k�+��(�81�YP�|��M6k���5_V^�*H����V��;=-:Z��h��̹j5�4��)��'�P~W}|��E>k5׍��1��QX�P�������X�
a�FSP0r��#3z�s+d!��-l�)+T����2����L�=�*�#�Zn��dv�caP��(݉���+���j��������Ë��
WQ�4ő_V�zy���t9����b[��=O\�5%&����w渜{*�P^6�Xc��}��A[i<~��
�L�w
�z׀��꾼�����64�t��X,���s�b��r���"�Q��'�z��J�z�3�A��Ú��YY���cNT�0��d�I�e��_sU�dH�gq��[;�y�.;�d2�lb���O�klhh<��tY�I�:��L��^���WffZZ��|A�.\�CS?�D"�8T�w�~���]9����sgJKD"�4����"V��P*%$o�P��X�雙�3�>1�O2�S��'�f�If�0����o�itn��+�(�[�
o�׮Kdm�5^���L/���Y�k��'�uN`'H?i^��
��k�'�;\ΩC~�6�����K���yy��&S����t�[r-�Fm�B��wl�fnYi�ӔX��`�LL�������}����?�DO�ј���un�m�O6k/՚g��Y-��) {��4N8��X&�W''2=��#{_�K�����X,�����a�Yuqd_qiR�D���ؘ��8�����|[gǣ/N=�t�p�L�L�8�++G"����=�Ž��۶��}�O���?�bwOjx�~<
I:�D�H��

\X%�[N�ض��dU�>U,�q?�gE���   `�S�?e�`�������w�y�u���'l��oؼd��7{a�H��:ߘ����S�q��ҊLcD��12:?����aN]�͒�NI)�����_S��o2��ʳጴ���7�V�n����l�I��*��e��$���m-�����Rjj���)ZmZ��ճ��&#C�x*2"��Sǧ�Q���VKD$qBk��2�p�i��lag���~s?���lm�׭8k���n�S����39颴����GFp��Y��,�3���������&y�@�[�����X[��<sf]�K:�Krn�J���P��#|��ӈpNvtitX_\��19��Y��hp�ct��F�#5%B�劔����t�S
eDZ�á�M]�#���3-M:��6����?�t��1Qv���W��+*T�VP���������bXހ?}��Ɓ��q�eڈB�+?�N�qؠ��J�c \�g�͛��<ϟ�7�wxV�/]�ލ��uҳ��s�`�+�))��YF�J*���V�����l����M1g    ��۫P�]ٽ� m��>.�5��F.@YXi��h�a;����EfϥK�� D��^�0v�2l%B��؁I��QY�Z+�����8재,����$9m�Օ'(��ώ��1��8��oţD�  (ɏ����~#rE��;;PN������)U�����%Ey�\�a_k[VVFz���h�s��6}z����:%EqJ&�����{;�+&��2]����-�ա������20vr:ɍ1U������I  ����1����^z���H�K.)R��
Њ�����<V�E�H��\eKr����q�9����A�}G�L�,$�g�V��p�ʕ�'��˿$�j.������o�'a�iSS�2I����q���e���}s��R�"z��WH4 ���W�wަ��7¶�N��$���aۀ$9�׽G�6ؗT��d���P5��R�|�Ѱ��k�Ғ�����4� �;�
b�a���
�����2��
��
�R"m�ݽU�Z
��$�X"�_���4�+�CC�'{�sMC����ġ�;����@���ں�vM/�>g�y�
��ZuV�� p��ݾ�?|��
��^]ڈ�~�X���(�z���Y�ŀ�b{�   ���l�n�(>����k���~½)���b��ڛ���\'_B��C��5�Ds10#]2HD�
k�
�Y��7I8`��S']W��'&*�������}��q3s�j}#f�S�ꪽ+���]�;���r,��W���Q��X&�c4'6bWǶwd�paёÅE<��N�v�oM�_�S��8��ꯩ�̹�Hm���7�
��d@�C8N�⺖��:�,������L@���.�I�/�T�L$isMv��dO�%[,��2*+1#���76���GG�d���o�d��2�Ǵm���{8�C�ū�2._�"�8�Gg����&�����_�lL�����o���R-��q��T)�������Κ��"��`ԛr̹�����!6;gR*�2=�V@�~�Ԝ�� //#-&od����A��&��^˔��Q}��5���$V/T�{�/s�=�HM�/m&]��7�vw>�ޞe��qU푣e��>�^Q�m[G{S��SS�m);+���0����v���(}bp�j��;��ϮU��w�k��   ���ԭ�(�~�#�`��  6���/��B��`�Bچ��QN�r��e~���,�&�xͫ��؁�]ez}ۡ�##�m��2_��|�9sz<(
�c�v����|`���?  ���J�
    ��x�R���MMnw�}D�[��`k��(��8�#�A�>�������f ǲ.�   1J@I�<1I���4I��h�.J��B��vp����ۖϻ��@h����$��<���&'M�MN���-+Þsm���hu�m�j��/8���a9�~k�z~��B�� � ���r�Tn{<�o�&&��ֽd���8�7������3�a+����W*B��
�a6N�¬k@{-l��(�E&p��S��;�6M�u����ef���"AEcsZ>{��oa��뤰����#V��$���(� �>Ksu���ܝK
��+���$sZ!�t�T�}��E����Bz�
�M�2p��"<�ֈ1�Gy��Q���p��B�?�8{�Z%�֐����7n�� k��0=���`����i)��}}c�Ҳk��l��n���44�Ln��X�E���g{��+��@V���E���q�����s�\�7��>'O��O����:mE�����SyeY�%$�����h��J���sx��؈�쨨 Cee�V�ݒ����N��+pc��"�N�>��N�4�7%���Ī�+��J%�L
%��)�R�H�(�%"\���n��A\V�W�U��   ���#{A  ?������V�_dO鋟�.k^�Q��)pz�ή�z�13]�Y��mv-<Ϙ��N��4&�;�c�B��=�i��];���!���x<����R�<"L� ��p�:ɣh*�о��ᚚ�D�z�k�Cޠg��(.���I��lB����{+���g������KB��x��ղ�`��Ԑr
�3�܇~~��ՁY"��ҳ��x���o����|�r|�n�Q�KE�u��/�U����~�׈a�����#�g����U��AZ�!l]�z[�q�Շ�5�*��ZK���6����CR����!"��b�D*�r��.0=���D�${�ڊ��V��M�*�>�.+�'������*���W~0�J����9���<���<�;a0�|���PCУ�������3
���4Aǰ�(��Dz����u�.��tN�ِ.[���[�a�ߪ7k.�#J?X��b�����8�f�J�g��JK[�纻rs������WL��˗  ��M���~o̐x~~~��Bˈc���_�R9�k�rG���ZK:D�'6;�j�e긜l�F��2K%��FU
��ً���W��3�Y��+0\�B��sY�wgy���I2�c�*�k9O���ef��[˩��Ζ���L(�ɋ<Q�0GF�s�ڎ�ysSpD��h����,��bI�K�46[q��֚�K��Rs�P���T�^eI�or���b��*�{�l���k.yo��$��I�c�`��=���7��Շa��ٽ�X.�~P�sh�[��@kX~?��������G�Ym\>�{d�V��<P����k��>���㛲'zz
�\'�r������1'��;��3g�\
��U�o�%Y�%�������N]�>>A�T*��I�����8�\.��M�Ư����C�_?2=���G��׵;z���ѽS�M

ճ�X
�����5%^��XS��?��iձr�L�����蒓4�J�B�IJ^E�CCSMO�=z��ѱ�u�#G�<������O���͝�\��A3i��D#=��@C\�� m�V�#�����[���(u�=�rW�(�l�!q�[���r�;W�p�W,��S���i�kU�V%_�v��z��
W�a�rD̀b�������{�Ƥw������UX���,�\�y�^���_
�+�es���[.�|��LK?�\7���+[�.b3��+�G�GbX��˝@�#��ߏ��و���*((��$���iiIL���{��LYYT��lӶ��`T���)H�G��k�.44�<6��?LM嚟HK��x���f��m�h�F$]]�}X��V�:�Fswc�w����G��2> �q'��d/��%��:�˸O.��_�YM�m��  (�7�M�nSTbj��U��O@|�8�i��K\��Fb�����[e��'���Z   �֪���X[�x��
)��2�J��ѥ�|�X��B�_A-��^��c<z�[5��[]q�?#��j���X��"���G���'��#S��F�/i4��';���^�P�e�� �țe�f��O]����V��e����    8}���`  Æ
�;���U�/�l� އ~d��ę����4�l�����non�� �ŝ�{{�j�2r/T$Rg]��b�-=Uj����>�h�4h;$|��RSKq��tuu|^�kRf�>�B.p5�ȍ���S��x��?��b�;��()�ⅲj�,�Gi6mk�:u����A?�ɢWݝ��gi`ƅ�O�_Е�ZZ����?{����R�>�������;�=��گ�k������� �I��_��ȦV��ۙ���hUt��~Ҟ��;�:���4�eK�RN<3媇i�  �J�⿸��ep9�7v8��i7
qzfEeKK
c��<6VE}��8B�H���_����!F�a-��
�Μ�{�����䶟��6��e����Z���j�+GH���5���̗5����2�}��h��q��������~����|�C�B`6�C�fW��&��Ej����<o���ʧ���|��~�������K�!�6�˿`׊1v�yJ������u~cH��_f�t�TfSS���V֦��^��YR�˸�kR��<�#�1*����ϕ�Q@�s���ߦ�̹��ij�Nb�\N�C�dF@�7vtB{�,�4=��ٕn��I�F*�",l;4�޳�r�0����,����.-����if����9��.>3�ז�$�۷=�g5��,O�{�8�E/:��9�x�©ϫ�����xzv��z~q���RueI�����|k�ف�V\�N���ӕ�O?���yz.ޖ��P�z���X�Z���GК[�Ľ���f���l*x���yub���/h���j0��2�P�-������_��jjilr�;��j-ŅZ�Z]Z6���Œ��Y�v�v6��<�����2���Tê��9<\_�c�Zw��䄆
fy�O[��3bU��،�Ғ]�hu���� ��!�Σb�s�w�bT�1*ujZA���=���z�S�d���S������V��%2�;���G�,`q�!�c{MU��Bqm�������+�66���bH�2�LV�@��a^��2��"��V��/D��T�e��i~A���o3?�Ԕ�b0�
,i?�WT4�Y0���(^SP����Je�Db�L���ۇ�a,����i)���{[+��J��C��+yzh��o�!׮M^+k��U滋�C��/�,p�S��%��J���%����N��
Cƣ��oc�)ל�K�J�B)�DE[#����1����;Ϭ|DD?���P(����

�O��3�
I�C��"��8������P��9����eN>�p
\C�z�   ����Nh͹�u���H3�]&���TU�ݹs�lP����$�w�� �OAl�#V����s��N���|�<%`[�,���_��x����U    k�+Zqܓ��!�J�?[��sԌ߂AӣjB�z��f>�����MZ��)3RQB4@��:�w��������>�fx��=�1����7�)�/�����ߠ����
�� T��uxv�F%����y��7��U{-��}�lFż���
����՛�-8w
���5$���>ۏaا��D�0�F�@F������~`�!�{�w
����y�����pL��]͵
d����X��#���O�f����C���t)�{s�×����S�� ���5�k�~����
�Q� '��}�� �z4ώbW�Lc�&�7    q��AF��);UG���t �O?DDo?��>���(d4���J�/xJ��ca��{�/C�Co��E�E�a3a���e�3�仒��c���_��K���%K�]�ݖK����7�w���+�w�k�8��(C���Q�E/Fs1�դ�G�_�f�.Ɲ�{R-P�U�2�4�?����D  �5Xc��|���V�=���!�O��u��D�)��b��<B�}���ͻO�xηO����o�+��}�4�/��y(+|�b��
�}�q������>�>��|�Fb<�J�~tM�q����b4Y���������������0��.B��9���|O�r�:����p/{�$�C�k?���}2��^���l�J��~3\���3�����ZX{Wg]����3m��m�8��n<��O[뙷_�Vn����>k>YI��
жZ�
��&��9�`���>���X0`�
endstream
endobj
21 0 obj
9294
endobj
19 0 obj
<< /Type /Font
/Subtype /CIDFontType2
/BaseFont /Cairo-Regular
/CIDSystemInfo << /Registry (Adobe) /Ordering (Identity) /Supplement 0 >>
/FontDescriptor 17 0 R
/CIDToGIDMap /Identity
/W [0 [233 737 1102 218 267 265 574 637 292 292 598 626 522 501 462 348 344 556 556 556 556 556 556 968 216 556 556 556 267 639 265 293 261 587 634 531 602 654 273 598 297 265 623 556 412 813 661 669 631 479 579 305 292 1012 551 265 547 498 526 671 591 541 297 821 621 1110 265 810 292 694 551 631 889 264 264 602 626 293 985 523 853 574 639 784 655 1047 556 653 589 877 589 757 523 587 834 217 743 538 528 524 829 219 534 737 ]
]
>>
endobj
20 0 obj
<< /Length 1139 >>
stream
/CIDInit /ProcSet findresource begin
12 dict begin
begincmap
/CIDSystemInfo << /Registry (Adobe) /Ordering (UCS) /Supplement 0 >> def
/CMapName /Adobe-Identity-UCS def
/CMapType 2 def
1 begincodespacerange
<0000> <FFFF>
endcodespacerange
8 beginbfrange
<0000> <0000> <0000>
<0001> <0001> <FEC7>
<0003> <0034> [<0020> <0623> <FE91> <FEEE> <FEE3> <FEE8> <FE98> <FEA0> <FECA> <0054> <0065> <0073> <0074> <0072> <0031> <0033> <0034> <0039> <0036> <002B> <0040> <002E> <0038> <0032> <0030> <0627> <FEF9> <FEF3> <FE8E> <0631> <FECB> <FED8> <FEAA> <FED7> <FEE2> <FEDF> <FEA4> <FEB0> <FE97> <FEA6> <0035> <002F> <FEBB> <0644> <FEE4> <FED0> <062F> <0629> <FEE0> <FEF4> ]
<0036> <0040> [<FEA3> <FEE7> <0639> <0061> <0064> <004E> <0041> <0648> <FEAE> <FEB3> <0645> ]
<0042> <004D> [<FE8B> <FE90> <FE92> <FEDE> <FE9F> <FECC> <064A> <0028> <0029> <FED3> <FECE> <FE84> ]
<004F> <0057> [<0062> <FEB4> <FE94> <FEFB> <062A> <FEEC> <FED2> <0037> <FEDC> ]
<0059> <0059> <FEF2>
<005B> <0067> [<0077> <0071> <0050> <004D> <003A> <FEC4> <0053> <0075> <0070> <006D> <0069> <006E> <FEC3> ]
endbfrange
endcmap
CMapName currentdict /CMap defineresource pop
end
end

endstream
endobj
7 0 obj
<< /Type /Font
/Subtype /Type0
/BaseFont /Cairo-Regular
/Encoding /Identity-H
/DescendantFonts [19 0 R]
/ToUnicode 20 0 R>>
endobj
22 0 obj
<< /Type /FontDescriptor
/FontName /QWAAAA+Cairo-SemiBold
/Flags 4 
/FontBBox [-224 -430 1667 1084 ]
/ItalicAngle 0 
/Ascent 1303 
/Descent -571 
/CapHeight 1303 
/StemV 50 
/FontFile2 23 0 R
>>
endobj
23 0 obj
<<
/Length1 8132 
/Length 26 0 R
/Filter /FlateDecode
>>
stream
x��Y{L[W�?�������m����0����c ��Ƥ!   ��4��v:)m3���(�IәN�ae�l�n ���j�TݨEQ���������v5.��kl �f�����s�9�~�{��c�BBt�h�m8�+�/��
�;�������P�#B�Ho_W���*��g�B���2B�����}���-оq�XOכ�?>�P"4Q�P��qdDg�ͽO9�5�g�߱� ��DG���܈Z�w �FA�Jў��<�P�j�*�=��UZ�v!:�(JA��-^&�����tоA��nE�d�h�J�Ó�L���6��^��FK0r�����(3ʖ��Ok��%�����H�{�2c5yjm:w��-f�ٸ��ڗ��EI�D2n��,�HĲ�heTT�Q�j��"`�h��J��R�.�gR  d��t
#`Z�� �����T*_�z��{�PēU�W�i���kc�ñM�ݞw�������W!�P$�FJ���~��D�Wb"#��]]��n�2�8""6:R&�0��%;D})��7ӯ�0��ۄd��{�F��@�lq����$�l��v����N,@�1�b6��y2�8@�� "����eeRbrdr�Bv�j�g�w��������h�H�����$�Y�r�$�Yyr���R��-�Q��:�bPR�d�y���|[��)#'�޽�V��y��_����W�>Q7@�%
?M<��U���HT�Rs{���8a��XҹU�hCxD5<~�(D��=
��c�Ҹ���R۱���r0��
���Z�I�$B�&�B�Z��V17�����7ߪ�U(_���ޜ�Z�
�7Iκ��~+V����lSH<�[���?E$E��-��y�E�ށ�,"��/#�s����|�1�1Y�q:����Vi��������
���S-EKQ��rg�����Y����~���K�Ѥ�!3#9�h,,.*�}�j�ޢ�l]�"�p�����*fɖ���1`�S�g�=Ǣ4؁t��M�6a�����w�8ɑ$'9��%�L�O?�:9������5��╔D������Ӈ��t?c}T�yŴ��
��l�]��ǫ�������c�@"�J�2�(��N�hl��-��MM���b�`�.):ztFW���ju7&�5~��1�m�6������_=U���Z��Vuᵅv�+�yym1T�d����0��T��f
V���� �m��K����-e��i���#�G�G��R�JZ[����~smffx�����-�힃���mO�N�p�y�]��!�-s��g���=�:GC��e[��ɪG�}O�V;k4�\����S��dYd�,Y�{��.��*��拘W�1�
�>?�8���� hd�v�Xԥ�O��(�p*)��f���i��D
�0  �Ă�%"(���ޞ��'Ƌ
��p^�����^����Z�J"��W׸���N[I�1���sp����@�^e4���c�;h;�9npQ!�1ۺ�����<�)��Їr�@�����]H��R�t���
�����8�O��������`��h�� L"
Sě��/�K�>Ob0��^�[�����-%e��ujDٲ_�"�t�6"]=G��x����zsi    +�a�    z��N"'��i�z<���nڊ��ldF�?YE�wo�յ�g�_���{��>���3}..�?;;���ݜ�:g����kܪ�9�<�c����h�*H��Au� T>�����ѹk����~mm=�8d+�W(�m�ǖ�9ffg�Xi+9>����b/�ӌ�v��Ĉ  5�ު�Q(g�摑�)��<x������Ee�H���Qk���NC"�0t�L����Ǣ��.��T���������M=~z=ĕ�re�������KPhӊ�YSS���L���ە���[��۶��P%���#�j���2v���[��,]��eWU�[�u�
Xk����!�ܝ�v�lxn�G�{��
�'�زZ��3^���0=g�%6����y")��f��ɕ;&KP�"�C�|7K��ܾ�ͥ�����>ϡ�j�J�MM��GH��ZF���3��f����sc�$f�PS����t��m��G�ed�J\�#�X$V&Z�����H�e«���d�
>�����D��" m��mCR��X4����F��d��#���ʪ�I]zZ>�$J�#?
�����ķ�|{qq��޴��������[�mOh��ss��{��ŉ��t�̉�J�W�r�$״�
yk�3ssk��(&��6���z����3������7>?E�L���Q��CQtC�y�Iwϩ�{��f.+���N-ܿ�����5u�P�3^�Y�#�8�{2����<]F��}�P 0@��~j�>�Nn"���r$�HC Y9����oMTtJ�)�X��(��HY�!A�A�����l?=���՘��Lmn�!/q�bqd��"��,e|��2��    _��{)����b9E���
߸����&@��X����Q�5�.ԏ�o=��P�������&NE} 3zo��b7T����O����I��b�ڏ��r�>�\nз�ǈ���qa��џ��%��ں�#��JUJ6�Ⱦ�/��|��a�+}<��~v�_�.-q��2��7:[�
�iٷ/]�p\����Dx��e��7�� l+�]��ȹ�I��*!��{��7>l�+��·ȑ�e�ɭIۻ-}���N�"�yq��o4�72�i�N�8��C}���p0a�����1YH(;�����ȱ6BW.=�~��@(�x�
Fc���7eP�7��xTE�J�npT�lx�V�q����k�����,��T��#c�/���NM-��v����f�8�ϭ<���F���s�U���=�6Pt�f�.R��S$�վ���&d!g⵸%��������w�U\�6ݐWT�o��{�\�]��v�-C!���ru��l?YRʁ�g�C��3&���F���_p�J�V�
�݌U<�[�j���,��IK���&���QK#�����۽�V��Uh��K8-�n�U�g����ĝՇ[CP��!R�+�-� �N^�j�����Z���+�>����v��8�ۃ(�bB��&�wnA���;gs�S�XÍ�Q��?ہ��+�A��ظ��m��-)������    ���!���89�l��P�~�ط;:K۬E
eLlV&��^{}�%)����>�������f��hT����[ Ĭ,qXµH�(V��]iMM�����'�Uz}EU?���Ӽ������X@�;B0�6�3⬋�"t�|��>����V8X���:���rF\��d/p t�\��
���� �  �ܗM>�hp�d���YQ^�r��c������u�8YUh�+���%�Ӑik�5)}���Zw��d)�F�0Q�4�(L�qU��|���eQ�
���XxT�D�ն����כo�86
?vL�
�~� ��Z���T���{R4��}^�?.�-$$U��(��T)��=��''=�Ғ�dl-<z��f�6-:J��n.��X!W����NO�XbTj{�+g���z�#�����]G�\,)�
��[-}=�?�-)NP(��Ň_�~���\ �G�p����E���ϴ��>�:�g)t2P`��6�F��W���K��R�DԭI}廉���;yo[���A{-1W�y
�s�Ig�s�E���>G9���{�ss�)2��3&�I������I��y�}2r2a�m�$�ANA
�+Z����O���!��'x{�[<?�R������?�J�k�K�Cݣi��  ��3�
*�&T��7D5�K��6vY�%i���<��fH���.�~�n�W��<��DP������.h�����_'�}�SAch����:�v�p=��,=�q��.C���Q<�c���IB��-����qt
��A4��h�=z��Pk��>x��?c�A����~t���F�(�3�U�`�QT�v�5s��pf���Jh�!#�u��.���Jf�a��ʡu�B��5ǡ��4y<�E��+��9?g��fhs�B�(�����fv���(���q����jG��qa�*��ۺ���7�;9
�}��unoc�?��
endstream
endobj
26 0 obj
4214
endobj
24 0 obj
<< /Type /Font
/Subtype /CIDFontType2
/BaseFont /Cairo-SemiBold
/CIDSystemInfo << /Registry (Adobe) /Ordering (Identity) /Supplement 0 >>
/FontDescriptor 22 0 R
/CIDToGIDMap /Identity
/W [0 [233 279 285 604 604 314 217 292 641 305 821 326 703 640 676 277 277 797 641 536 552 557 664 632 1142 770 652 557 1012 306 317 635 843 584 483 904 277 292 669 555 223 555 ]
]
>>
endobj
25 0 obj
<< /Length 671 >>
stream
/CIDInit /ProcSet findresource begin
12 dict begin
begincmap
/CIDSystemInfo << /Registry (Adobe) /Ordering (UCS) /Supplement 0 >> def
/CMapName /Adobe-Identity-UCS def
/CMapType 2 def
1 begincodespacerange
<0000> <FFFF>
endcodespacerange
4 beginbfrange
<0000> <0000> <0000>
<0001> <0017> [<0627> <FEDF> <FEA4> <FEA0> <FEB0> <0020> <FE97> <FED4> <FE8E> <FEBB> <FEF4> <FEDE> <FECC> <FEE4> <FE91> <FEE7> <062A> <FED8> <FEAA> <0648> <FEA3> <FEDC> <0645> ]
<0019> <001B> [<0637> <FEF9> <FE9F> ]
<001D> <0029> [<FE92> <FEE0> <FECE> <FEB3> <FEEE> <062F> <064A> <0631> <FEF3> <0644> <0035> <002E> <0030> ]
endbfrange
endcmap
CMapName currentdict /CMap defineresource pop
end
end

endstream
endobj
6 0 obj
<< /Type /Font
/Subtype /Type0
/BaseFont /Cairo-SemiBold
/Encoding /Identity-H
/DescendantFonts [24 0 R]
/ToUnicode 25 0 R>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<<
/Type /Pages
/Kids 
[
5 0 R
]
/Count 1
/ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC]
>>
endobj
xref
0 27
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000009 00000 n 
0000021374 00000 n 
0000000157 00000 n 
0000000252 00000 n 
0000000675 00000 n 
0000021234 00000 n 
0000015451 00000 n 
0000000289 00000 n 
0000000333 00000 n 
0000000509 00000 n 
0000000374 00000 n 
0000000572 00000 n 
0000000992 00000 n 
0000003988 00000 n 
0000000796 00000 n 
0000000972 00000 n 
0000004009 00000 n 
0000004219 00000 n 
0000013626 00000 n 
0000014259 00000 n 
0000013605 00000 n 
0000015590 00000 n 
0000015801 00000 n 
0000020127 00000 n 
0000020511 00000 n 
0000020106 00000 n 
trailer
<<
/Size 27
/Info 1 0 R
/Root 12 0 R
>>
startxref
21472
%EOF
```

Tried solutions from other questions
For example

`

```
<object width="100%" height="100%" data="data:application/pdf;base64,'+res+'" type="application/pdf" />
```

`
Tried with encodeURI etc
Probably tried with whole answers from other questions, nothing to help.
Getting or empty white screen, or error...
With atob also getting an error:

> angular.js:14642 DOMException: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope that it will help to somebody

```
 const blob = new Blob([res], { type: 'application/pdf' });
            const blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            window.open(blobURL, '_blank');


return this.http.get(url, {
        headers: this.authHeaders,
        responseType: 'arraybuffer', <--- !!!!
    })
```